# Material UI v4 AutoComplete: popup menu won't stay open upon multi-select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

With Reactjs I'm using Material UI (core v4.12.3, lab 4.0.0-alpha.60) autocomplete which has been set up as a multiselectible drop down and I'm having trouble keeping the menu open. Whenever an option is selected the popup menu closes and I have to manually open it again just to select another option.
I have already set disableCloseOnSelect={true} But it still doesn't work

From trying to create a minimal example i noticed the issue seems to be due to a  MaterialTable component as shown in this example here:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/agitated-payne-h5hqk?codemirror=1

In this example if you expand the drop down, and pick one option the menu closes hence you have to re-expand in order to select a second option

However, if you remove the material table/component/toolbar lines (Such that the render method only returns the autocomplete)

```
<MaterialTable
  components={{
    toolbar: props => (
```

After removing the above you would then see the expected functionality is now seen (expand the dropdown, select an option, the menu still remains open for you to select a second option)

I'm not very experienced on the front end side but does anyone have any advice?

The example link is a very stripped down version and I'm not sure how feasible it would be for me to just remove this without breaking something